# How do I implement my XML layout file into a viewmodel() in android studio 4.1 with Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I'm a relative beginner to android programming and I want to have it so my fragments display the layout files which are assigned to them through a view model. I'll be providing only one fragment and view model pair as the 3 others which I have are practically the same except some names and text is swapped around.

Here's  my TimetableFragment.kt

```
package com.example.intranetapp

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider

class TimetableFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var timetableViewModel: TimetableViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        timetableViewModel =
            ViewModelProvider(this).get(TimetableViewModel::class.java)
        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news, container, false)
        val textView: TextView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_news)
        timetableViewModel.text.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            textView.text = it
        })
        return root
    }
}
```

Here's my TimetableViewModel.kt

```
package com.example.intranetapp

import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel

class TimetableViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val _text = MutableLiveData<String>().apply {
        value = "This is timetable Fragment"
    }
    val text: LiveData<String> = _text
}
```

And here's my MainActivity.kt

```
package com.example.intranetapp

import android.os.Bundle
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupActionBarWithNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupWithNavController

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val navView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)

        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(
            R.id.timetableFragment, R.id.dueworkFragment, R.id.newsFragment, R.id.gradesFragment))
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }
}
```

I'm not getting any errors when running the application, i'm more just wondering how i can make it so my XML file Timetable.XML is shown when creating the viewmodel rather than text in the middle of the screen which says "This is Timetable fragment"

I'm sorry if i come across as a dumb coder, i'm just struggling to fix this issue and this was the first place to come to mind as google searches aren't helping

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
private val _text = MutableLiveData<String>().apply {
    value = "This is timetable Fragment"
}
```

Setting the value happens when ViewModel is initializing. But you start observing this LiveData after initializing, so you loss this value.
You should add method in your viewModel:

```
fun setTextValue() {
    _text.value = "This is timetable Fragment"
}
```

and call it after `timetableViewModel.text.observe()`

Comment: Sorry for not being more clear, i meant as in displaying an already set up XML layout file using a view model